# Firefox not kept up to date

Tags: updates, firefox

I am amazed this never happened for so long but I noticed that Firefox is no longer being upgraded on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS so I am stuck on version 36.

Apparently somehow linked to the flash player being outdated. A warning came up and I discovered the problem with Firefox.

Anyone knows how to update manually and why this happens?

**UPDATE: 3 days later**

Dear all,

thanks for your helpful answers!
However, surprisingly, 1 hr after having posted my question and NOT HAVING CHANGED anything on the system yet the update came up automatically!

Completely weird, isn't it?
Apparently nothing happens for at least 2 - 3 months and, then, just when starting to investigate on it the update comes more or less instantly.

Does this appear logic or normal to you?
Or could that be a hint to malware or something comparable controlling my computer? Something known about such threats?

Thanks again to all of you!

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update`, [edit] your question and add output of `apt-cache policy firefox` terminal command. And also output of `cat /etc/lsb-release`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a hold on the package.  You can release it with

```
sudo apt-mark unhold firefox
```

*Sorry to post as an answer instead of comment, but for some I only have enough rep for answers (seems backwards?)*

Comment: This is an answer, not a comment. Comments are supposed to be remarks about the question: just because an answer is short doesn't mean it should be a comment. The reputation limit is to prevent new users from making the common mistake of putting short answers in the comments.

Comment: ... which is why it "seems backwards", because such users tend to make the mistake of putting comments in answers, instead. Both are, of course, wrong, and the given justification of "I only have enough rep for answers" is _not_ an excuse. Mleh.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version for Firefox in the [Standard Ubuntu Repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firefox&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) is `39.0+build5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1`

Check, that you have enabled the `trusty-security` category. The screenshot is for Vivid, but that makes no difference.

[image]

After that

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

If there is no upgrade for your Firefox, check the hold status for firefox.

If you have an output like this

```
$ apt-mark showhold
firefox
```

remove the unhold attribute with

```
sudo apt-mark unhold firefox
```

You will see this message

> Canceled hold on firefox.

Now start

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

again

Answer (score -1):

#### A temporary solution:

download the `.deb` file directly from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/firefox). just choose your architecture flavor and then you can install:

```
sudo dpkg -i firefox_39*.deb
```

---

#### You can use another repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

---

#### As added information you can install new version manually:

**Download (now it's version 39)**

Download the release from: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/#firefox

**Extract:**

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar xvf firefox-39.0.tar.bz2
```

**Move to /opt**

```
sudo cp firefox39/ /opt
```

**Make Links:**

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/firefox /usr/bin/firefox_old

sudo ln -s /opt/firefox39/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

And that's. Enjoy

Comment: Why install it manually, if same version is in the repos? It will not be updated.

Comment: OP asks for `Anyone knows how to update manually and why this happens?`

Comment: We need to find why this happens, and it will be fixed. If he updates your way, he will ask the same question after next version is released.

Comment: @Pilot6 in this point you are right